# Cache HttpClient objects with a custom critetia

Tags: java, caching, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm working on an application where it uses Apache HttpClient objects to resolve HTTP and HTTPS requests (GET, POST ...). And I'm looking for a method to cache those HttpClient objects for reuse. And I should be able to define a caching criteria, **in this case the caching should be based on the host name of the service request url**.

i.e. if I'm sending GET requests for a specific url (abc.net/content , abc.net/content2 ... ) then those requests should be handled through a single HttpClient object. And that HttpClient object should be kept in a cache so that It will be used for future request in similar manner.

I'm referring to some resources and found [this](https://github.com/otto-de/jsonhome/blob/master/jsonhome-client/src/main/java/de/otto/jsonhome/client/HttpJsonHomeClient.java) and [this.](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.client.cache.HttpCacheStorage) But no idea how to use them for the purpose.

What should be the correct way to do this ? **Can I do this using a HashMap< String, HttpClient >** ? Or is there a better way to do this using ApacheHttp ?

Comment: Are your sure you want to cache the HttpClient and not the response data of the request?

Comment: Why you like to cache the HttpClient? If configured correctly the HttpClient "caches" existing connections to the server internally and reuses them to speed up processing.

Comment: How many HttpClient you want to cache? How you want to limit resource usage to meet your capacity constrains in your runtime? What exactly is the difference between the HttpClient instances in the cache?

Comment: If an httpClient serve a request to a particular host we need to use that httpClient object to cater the future requests to the same host. That's the difference of HttpClient objects in the cache. Number of objects should be configurable.